# Is there a way to retrieve the Writing System for a given Language in Qt?

Tags: qt, localization, internationalization

I recently upgraded an existing Qt application to utilize QTranslator for deployment in multiple countries.  The previous programmer defined all the fonts in style sheets, but it seems that not all languages are supported by the designated font-family and this is causing QLabels to lose their styling.  My solution is to dynamically determine a suitable font (we're not at the stage where we might need custom fonts).

Is there a way to use the the result of QLocale::language() to generate a QFontDatabase::WritingSystem so I can run QFontDatabase::families() and query the results for an appropriate font?

Comment: Can't find any built in functionality for this.  I only have a few languages, so associating QLocale.language() values to QFontDatabase::WritingSystem values works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a built-in function for Qt 4.7, but you can create an associative array linking languages from QLocale::language() to QFontDatabase::WritingSystem values.